# Get latest updated timestamp from sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've a table:

```
ID | CMD_ID | VALUE | CREATED_TIMESTAMP
1       45   'test'   123456
2       46   'news'   123456
3       45   'test'   123457
4       46   'news'   123457
5       45   'TEST'   123468
6       46   'news'   123468
```

I want to get the each CMD_ID once and the timestamp from the latest time the value for that CMD_ID was changed.

How do I write an sql-query (for sqlite) that gives me the result:

```
ID | CMD_ID | VALUE | CREATED_TIMESTAMP
2       46   'news'   123456
5       45   'TEST'   123468
```

?

My solution so far:

```
select * from (select * from test as t where t.id 
in (select id from test group by value) order by id desc) group by 
cmd_id order by id;
enter code here
```

That gives me the correct answer but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Shouldn't your results include the row with id 6 instead of id 2?

Comment: What happens if the data is news/news/test/news?  Do you want the last news or the first one?

Comment: @GordonLinoff if you're talking about one CMD_ID I want the last one. That is, the last time a value with a certain CMD_ID was changed.

Comment: @iveqy . . . I don't think forpas's solution does this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no? In all my tests it has succeeded. Can you give me an example where it doesn't work?

Comment: @iveqy . . . In this example (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jbnDtjFvSCph7BunZCxkoN/0), I assume you 123472 and not 123471 for 47.

Comment: @GordonLinoff now I'm confused, I don't find 47, 123472 or 123471 in that fiddle

Comment: @iveqy . . . For some reason the changes didn't "stick".   Here is the version:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8KxBcq43r59uYJuGk5xmBP/0.

Comment: @GordonLinoff nice catch! You're perfectly right. I would want to have row 2,5 and 9 as a result.

Answer (score 1):

In sql sever you can get max value from these

SELECT id, max(timestamp) timestamp FROM table GROUP BY id

Comment: sqlite> select id, max(created_timestamp), created_timestamp from test group by id;

will return all 6 rows and that is not my desired outcome

Comment: @iveqy He probably meant to use `cmd_id`, not `id`. That returns two rows (But shouldn't be counted on because *which* row of a group is returned is arbitrary).

Answer (score 1):

You need to group twice and then join to the main table:

```
select tablename.* from tablename 
inner join 
(select cmd_id, max(minstamp) as maxstamp from
  (select cmd_id, value, min(created_timestamp) as minstamp 
  from tablename 
  group by cmd_id, value)
group by cmd_id) as t
on t.cmd_id = tablename.cmd_id and t.maxstamp = tablename.created_timestamp
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jbnDtjFvSCph7BunZCxkoN/0)
**Edit**
After the new cases you provided I came up to this:

```
select tablename.* from tablename inner join (
select t.cmd_id, max(t.created_timestamp) maxstamp from (
  select * from (
    select 
      t.*, (
        select value from tablename tt 
        where 
          tt.cmd_id = t.cmd_id 
          and 
          tt.created_timestamp = (
            select max(created_timestamp) from tablename 
            where 
              cmd_id = t.cmd_id 
              and
              created_timestamp < t.created_timestamp
          ) 
      ) previousvalue
    from tablename t   
  ) t  
  where 
    t.previousvalue is null 
    or 
    t.value <> t.previousvalue
  ) t
group by t.cmd_id
) t 
on t.cmd_id = tablename.cmd_id and t.maxstamp = tablename.created_timestamp
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8KxBcq43r59uYJuGk5xmBP/1)
Try it this time exhaustively.

Comment: @iveqy *A value that has never changed should get its first date_created as its update time* these are your words from your comment. So what is the problem?

Comment: that's right. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8KxBcq43r59uYJuGk5xmBP/0 I expected the result to be row 2, 5 and 9. Is that really against something I said before? Because if it is, it's me beeing confused, but I don't think so. The latest value for cmd_id should be used as a latest update value. (I assume the problem is going from news->test->news that confuses your question)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party but still this might be useful.

There is a simpler solution. You can first order by descending timestamp, then group by id. The first (latest) entry will be taken for each group.

```sql
select * from (select * from test order by created_timestamp desc) group by id;
```

although it is best practice to use a version count (e.g. an auto incremented column which is unique (primary or alt key)) and sort by it instead of the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`row_number`](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/) window function for this. It will give each record the sequence number it has within a "partition" (defined by `cmd_id`). Once you have that number as extra information, you can filter for the records where that number is 1:

```
select id, cmd_id, value, created_timestamp
from   (
          select test.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by cmd_id order by created_timestamp desc) rn
          from   test
       )
where  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very careful.  Say you have data like this:

```
1    test
2    news
3    test
```

If you want the value from "1", then `group by` solutions will work.  If you want the value from "3", then the problem is a bit different.  The way your question is phrased, you seem to want "3".

The most recent versions of SQLite support window functions.  Let me assume that you are using an earlier version.

The following query identifies the final group of rows with the same value by assigning a value of `0` to `num_different_later`:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.cmd_id = t.cmd_id and
              t2.created_timestamp > t.created_timestamp and
              t2.value <> t.value
       ) as num_different_after
from t;
```

We can get the earliest timestamp using aggregation:

```
select cmd_id, value, min(created_timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             (select count(*)
              from t t2
              where t2.cmd_id = t.cmd_id and
                    t2.created_timestamp > t.created_timestamp and
                    t2.value <> t.value
             ) as num_different_after
      from t
     ) t
where num_different_later = 0;
```

Comment: I guess the last query should have num_different_after on the last line? That only gives me one result:
46 news 123456